# Rails Active Storage image upload to Heroku Postgres Add-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, rails-activestorage

I have created a rails blog app, where I upload images to my articles. I have deployed the app to Heroku with a Postgres add-on. When I upload the images, they display fine, but if I push a change, or the Heroku dyno is restarted, the images disappear.

I am aware that Heroku's database is ephemeral, but the support team have ensured the add-on isn't ephemeral and the images should remain there if the code is set up correctly.

I believe I need to change my 'storage.yml' file for my production. I can see how to change it for AWS, Google, Microsoft, et., but I'm wondering if anyone can help me set it up for Heroku's AWS based add-on, please?

I have the following credentials details from Heroku´s eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com AWS database:

Host:
Database:
User:
Port:
Password:
URI:
Heroku CLI:

I can't find any information on how to set it up, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Trying to set up the correct storage.yml file information

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty confused here.

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
> the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
> shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
> filesystem from the most recent deploy.

The ephemeral filesystem only effects ActiveStorage if you're using the default `:local` service which stores attachments in the local file system.

The database add ons are not ephemeral. Having the database get wiped on deploy would make their constumers very angry.

While you can store files in blobs in the database ActiveStorage does not ship with a service for database storage and YMMV with the [third party gems](https://github.com/blocknotes/active_storage_db) that provide it. Storing files in the database also comes with some [pretty significant downsides](https://medium.com/ensias-it/you-shouldnt-store-your-images-videos-in-a-database-6a78ffa277b2) and I would not recommend it.

Instead I would really recommend that you sign up for a cloud storage service like AWS S3 and just follow [the instructions in the Rails guides for integrating it](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#s3-service-amazon-s3-and-s3-compatible-apis).

Forget about [Heroku's AWS S3 addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) which may not work with recent versions of Rails (see the warning at the top of the guide), I'm a bit uncertain as to what it actually provides and YAGNI.